# How can I place a data dependency of a cc_library's shared object in the same directory as the shared object?

Tags: bazel

I have a cc_library() of a shared object (libname.so), and it requires a data file, data.xml, in the same directory as itself.

Bazel *.runfiles/ places the data file in the same relative path as in the software repository, but I want it as above. Thank you!

I've tried:

```
    cc_library( 
        name = "libname",
        srcs = ["libname.so"],
        data = ["data.xml"],
    )
```

I expected data.xml and libname.so to be in the same path (bazel-bin/proj/program.runfiles/repo/_solib_k8/_U_S_Slibname/) but the data file is in a directory relative to the project root. (bazel-bin/proj/program.runfiles/repo/src/data.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Best solution yet, runfiles executable works, but `bazel run program` fails to dynamically load libraries.

1) Group shared libraries and data files together:

```
filegroup(
    name = "libs_and_data",
    # This creates *.runfiles/.../path/to/data/files, for runpath
    data =glob(["*.so*"]) +  glob(["*.xml"]),
)
```

2) Manually build-link the shared libraries from their original folder,
3) Manually set the runpath to the runfiles data dependency directory that contains the shared libraries and data files.

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    data = [
        # Shared objects are data, not library deps, to avoid _solib in RUNPATH
        "//path/to/libs_and_data",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        # Explicit build-linking of libraries, because we are avoiding cc_library()
        "-lLibrary1",
        "-lLibrary2",
        "-Lpath/to/libs",
        # Point dynamic loader to runfiles location of libraries and datafiles
        # Only the *.runfiles executable will successfully load libraries
        "-Wl,-rpath='../../../path/to/libs'",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//path/to/headers",
    ],
)
```